# Showing that a specific subset of $R^n$ is path-connected (Spherical Shell)

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Given the set denoting a spherical shell, $$A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : m \leq ||x-a|| \leq M \} $$ where m and M are positive real numbers, and $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, prove that A is connected.  I think it's the easiest approach to show that this is path connected (visualizing it in the 3-dimensional space at least), but have no idea how to approach it.

I've tried assuming otherwise for a contradiction, but wasn't able to get anywhere.  I thought of trying to define a specific function as well, but wouldn't know how to generalize it for the nth dimension.

If anyone could throw me a bone, it'd be much appreciated!  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x, y \in A$.

Draw the ray from $a$ through $x$. Travel along that ray until  you hit the sphere centered at $a$ with radius $m$ at a point $x'$. Draw the ray from $a$ through $y$, and a point $y'$ like $x'$. There is an arc in the sphere* connecting $x'$ to $y'$, and there's your path.

---

* Prove this!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response!  To give a bit more context, I haven't done any work on arcs yet (on chapter 9 in Wade's Intro to Analysis), but I do get the general idea of your suggestion.  Since I have no experience with arcs, I was wondering if you had an alternative in mind - or is the proof simple enough to do with basic understanding of what an arc is (a special type of curve?)

Answer (score 0):

Assume first that $a=0$, then consider the map $\varphi:[m,M]\times{\mathcal{S}}^{n-1}$, $\varphi(r,x)=rx$, the domain is (path) connected and $\varphi$ is continuous and hence $\text{Im}~\varphi$ is (path) connected. Now $A=\text{Im}~\varphi+a$ and we know that $\cdot\rightarrow\cdot+a$ is heomomorphism, so $A$ is also (path) connected.